# Adding pattern based numbers on x axis in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have data only for the y-axis in 30 bins. I want to plot via Gnuplot by adding the x-axis in the Gnuplot script. Range for x-axis is [-5,2] with 30 bins. How can I add a pattern or formula-based numbers on the x-axis? Or can I add this pattern for the x-axis in the data file itself using any grep command?

Data for "file1.txt" (for example) is as follows;

```
0.000000e+00
0.000000e+00
1.936836e+01
1.347826e+02
2.204809e+02
3.531409e+02
4.656366e+02
6.431357e+02
8.020624e+02
----
----
---- up to 30 bins
```

**Outline for Gnuplot script is as follows;**

```
set style line 1 dt 1 lc rgb "black" lw 2 pt 1 ps default
set style line 2 dt 2 lc rgb "black" lw 5 pt 1 ps default

pl 'file1.txt' u ($0):($1) w l smooth bezier ls 1 title "title1",\
   'file2.txt' u ($0):($1) w l smooth bezier ls 2 title "title2"
```

Comment: What is your code and output so far? Please don't let us start from scratch, but please provide some minimal code and minimal example data. We will then tell you the missing bits.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have edited my question according to the required information.

Comment: Thanks for providing the code. You are using the pseudocolumn `$0` (check `help pseudocolumns`) already in your code, which is basically the line index starting from 0. So, what pattern or formula do you want to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a function to convert the x-axis values from the x index (default) to the desired values.  For example, assuming 30 data records mapped linearly to [-5, 2], and indexing x values is the default [0,1,2 ...,29]

f(x)=(x*7/29) - 5     (of course this should be -5, not -2)

maps the interval to [-5, 2].

Try `help stats` to determine number of records in data. (`STATS_records`)

```
$Data <<EOD
0.000000e+00
0.000000e+00
1.936836e+01
1.347826e+02
2.204809e+02
3.531409e+02
4.656366e+02
6.431357e+02
8.020624e+02
EOD
f(x)=(x*7/29) - 5            # map interval [0,29] to interval [-5,2] linearly
set xrange [-5:2]            # only 9 values in this data set
plot $Data using (f($0)):($1) with lines   # decorate as you see fit
```

[Quick sample plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uvzO.png)